# Have more rows on the selectbox widget

Tags: forms

I am trying to have more options visible in a select-box widget.

[image]

I have tried #size, to no avail.

```
function videomodule_form_video_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['field_video_taxonomie_video']['#size'] = 15;
}
```

Is there a way to do this with the form API?

Comment: Wouldn't a bit of CSS do it?

Comment: Per the [api](http://api.drupal.org), `[#size]` is valid for select and should dictate the size **for multiple** select. Try explicitly setting `$form['form_field']['#multiple'] = TRUE;`. If that is unaccepatable, you can use CSS to give the select box more height.

Comment: obligatory: make sure you clear the theme registry cache too (`drush cc theme-registry`)

Comment: @Chris #size was indeed the way to go, this field was in a collection and I needed to target an inner array.